# Java: Find Lines which start with double slashes "//"

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm goint to read someline from a text file. I want to remove lines which starts with `//`. I used below syntax to find those line but it is not working. I don't know the right REGEX for this. I would be glad if someone can correct me:

```
if (line.startsWith("//")){
       /* do the related stuff*/
       continue;
}
```

Comment: `startsWith` doesn't use regex

Comment: @Ferrybig so why it does not detect // in start of string?

Comment: @Tushar I tried that but did not work. I used "\\/\\/" since \ is escape character itself.

Comment: Thanks for not posting a wall full of code, but I think you went too far in the other direction. Some context and a working test would be useful (i.e. a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I ask because your code looks like it should work.

Comment: Definitely not "\\/\\/".

Comment: Did you want this to work on lines starting with "//" but possibly preceded by whitespace?

Comment: Why can't `if(line.substring(0,2).equals("//")) { /* do the related stuff*/}` be an option?

Comment: The line of code you show should work to identify a string that starts with two slashes. If it's not working, I wouldn't go looking for some more complicated solution like a regex or implementing a web service. I'd find the mistake and fix it. My first guess would be that "line" does not contain what you think it does. Could there be spaces before the "//"? Is there something wrong with how you're reading the file? Etc. If the simple code doesn't work, it's likely that more complex code will fail for the same reason.

Comment: `line` is a string variable name, `startsWith` is a function. Don't cornfuse them. Because then `endOfstring.startsWith()` could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

`line.startsWith("//")` is the right way of checking if a line starts in two forward slashes ([demo](http://ideone.com/uYxLJR)).

If you would like to check the same thing using regex, the expression would be `"^//.*$"`, where `^` is an *anchor* that stands for the beginning of the line, `$` stands for the end of the line, and `.*` stands for anything else in between ([demo](http://ideone.com/sF2Dk8)).

Comment: If you use `matches()` then there is no need for the anchors, and regex should simply be `"//.*"`. If you use `find()`, then there's no need to scan to end-of-line, and regex should be `"^//"`.